# ReactJS react-step-wizard focus to input after animation

Tags: reactjs

I use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-step-wizard to animate between forms. Each form is separated components.

How to set focus to input in active form after done slide animation?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try in [componentdidmount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)?

Something like this?

```
class App extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount(){
    this.nameInput.focus();
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <input 
          defaultValue="Won't focus" 
        />
        <input 
          ref={(input) => { this.nameInput = input; }} 
          defaultValue="will focus"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```